# What is RCC in embedded C using registers? A register, or a pointer to a register, or something else?

Tags: arm, register

Considering the following from [here](https://www.st.com/resource/en/reference_manual/dm00096844-stm32f401xb-c-and-stm32f401xd-e-advanced-arm-based-32-bit-mcus-stmicroelectronics.pdf):

```
RCC->AHB1ENR
```

Is **RCC** above the register itself or pointer to a register. Because the -> operator is used with the pointers as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2575048/arrow-operator-usage-in-c). They call this "RCC register" as if it is the register itself. What is the anatomy of this RCC?

So is it equivalent to: (*RCC).AHB1ENR? But if so RCC is not the register itself. Isnt it?

example of usage:
[image]

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/133873/discussion-on-question-by-gnz-a-basic-question-about-registers-in-embedded-c).

Comment: it is simply a structure that in this case points at a block of registers so that as used it is accessing a register directly.  note that using structs across compile domains are risky.  the folks that provide these solutions have a license that passes the risk to you, and also have pay-for support teams to help when things like this (and their library code) fails, use with caution, learn how this works in gory detail and own it.  know how to debug it when it fails.

Comment: @old_timer You wrote "it is simply a structure". But RCC  is the address of structure not the structure itself I guess isn't it? -> operator can only be used on a pointer. Did you want to say "RCC is simply the address of structure"?

Comment: RCC_TypeDef *  as shown in an answer below.  RCC_TypeDef is a structure (definition).  yes RCC itself is an address that points to a structure that is overlaid on the memory space to provide structure like access to individual registers.   It is elementary C though so no real magic about it.

Comment: RCC itself is an address/pointer to the beginning of the structure and RCC->AHB1ENR is an address/pointer to an element in that structure at some offset from  RCC_BASE.  Again this is elementary C, just look at the code.

Comment: RCC by itself is the address to the first register at RCC_BASE but you would have to override the type to use RCC by itself.  You could declare RCC as a structure itself, and then assign the address to it and then RCC.AHB1ENR as another way to do this.  But using pointers is slightly simpler.

Answer (score 13):

Neither, really. And this is just standard C, nothing specifically to do with an embedded environment.

It might be best to think of `RCC` as a pointer which points to the base address of the `RCC` peripheral.

In fact, `RCC` is a macro:

```c
#define RCC ((RCC_TypeDef *) RCC_BASE)
```

What it means is that `RCC` is just a name that expands to:
`((RCC_TypeDef *) RCC_BASE)`, where `RCC_TypeDef` is a structure that has the same layout and names as the RCC peripheral registers to allow easy accessing of them, and `RCC_BASE` is just another macro that holds the memory address where the RCC peripheral registers start.

`RCC->AHB1ENR = 3;` in the code for example, it expands to:

`((RCC_TypeDef *) RCC_BASE)->AHB1ENR = 3;`

The above line will take the literal number `RCC_BASE` which is a memory address from where the RCC peripheral registers start in memory, then type casts the literal address as a pointer which points to that given memory address, with a type of pointer that points to a structure called `RCC_TypeDef` at the given memory address, and the structure defines the memory layout and names of peripheral registers. Then the `->` dereferences the pointer to structure, and in that structure which starts from the RCC_BASE memory address, the member AHB1ENR which is at some added offset, is accessed, and in this example, the number 3 is stored to it.

So, your example will directly access a memory address at which a register happens to exist. The `RCC_BASE` is the base address where the peripheral registers start, and the added offset of the struct member `AHB1ENR` then allows you to access a memory address where the register with that name exists.

Therefore, the name of the register accessed is `AHB1ENR`.

And `RCC` is just a name of a macro that is made for your convenience to access the RCC peripheral registers via a struct that defines the register names.

Comment: Re *"...will directly access a register at memory address"*: Which is outside of any C standard (a GCC extension (or whatever compiler is used)). Assigning a value to a constant. Or dereferencing a constant. (Or with indirections.)

Comment: @PeterMortensen C was used to make operating systems and drivers before it was even standardized. I am sure nothing prevents taking a literal which is a memory address, casting it as pointer pointing to that memory address, and then dereferencing it in the same line to access data at that memory address.

Comment: @PeterMortensen: "assigning a value to a constant" would be a syntax error.  That's extremely different from casting a numeric literal to a pointer type, which is something that's just plain C syntax.  ISO C says it's undefined behaviour to access memory outside of any object, but there *is* an object at that address on systems that run this code: the I/O register.  If it's a `volatile char*`, ISO C says pretty much enough for code like this to work, although the wording of what `volatile` entails (and what a "volatile access" is) is vague enough that implementations have to define it.

Answer (score 7):

The datasheet you linked refers to the **registers** by their name because it is a hardware documentation. In this architecture the internal registers are memory mapped, meaning that the processor read/write from/to these registers using common memory read/write instructions.

The HAL you are using seems to use a structure with bitmasks to define the register fields. Using another HAL/Library ([libopencm3](https://github.com/libopencm3/libopencm3)) to explain the definitions:

```
#define PERIPH_BASE         (0x40000000U)
#define PERIPH_BASE_AHB1    (PERIPH_BASE + 0x20000)
#define RCC_BASE            (PERIPH_BASE_AHB1 + 0x01000)
#define MMIO32(addr)        (*(volatile uint32_t *)(addr))
#define RCC_CR               MMIO32(RCC_BASE + 0x00)
```

RCC_CR, in this case, is just a 32 bits number (an address). If you assign a 32 bits integer to this address, this value will be stored in the hardware register (despite the fact that you used the same instruction that stores a value in the RAM). Note that this is not even a **variable** in your code since the address is hard-coded and does not have to be stored in a **pointer** in RAM.

The definitions for each bit match the datasheet definition.

```
#define RCC_CR_PLLI2SRDY            (1 << 27)
#define RCC_CR_PLLI2SON             (1 << 26)
#define RCC_CR_PLLRDY               (1 << 25)
#define RCC_CR_PLLON                (1 << 24)
#define RCC_CR_CSSON                (1 << 19)
#define RCC_CR_HSEBYP               (1 << 18)
#define RCC_CR_HSERDY               (1 << 17)
#define RCC_CR_HSEON                (1 << 16)
// [...]
```

To configure this register, you build the 32 bits value using these definitions and write it to the reference given by RCC_CR. Again, this is not the same HAL you are using, but look how simple this memory mapped access becomes:

```
uint32_t on(void) // dummy example for write/read access
{
    RCC_CR = RCC_CR_PLLON | RCC_CR_PLLI2SON;
    return RCC_CR;
}
```

resulting in the following code:

```
00000000 <on>:
    // stores the memory map address (0x40021000) in r3:
    0:  4b02        ldr r3, [pc, #8]    ; (c <on+0xc>)
    // stores the new value encoding the bits (0x5000000) in r2:
    2:  f04f 62a0   mov.w   r2, #83886080   ; 0x5000000
    // stores the contents of r2 to the "memory" addressed by r3:
    6:  601a        str r2, [r3, #0]
    // reads the register ("memory") contents to the return register (r0)
    8:  6818        ldr r0, [r3, #0]
    // returns from the function call:
    a:  4770        bx  lr
    // the "register address" is encoded in the code (following the function return):
    c:  40021000    andmi   r1, r2, r0 ; (decoded as if it were a instruction)
```

RCC_CR is used as if it were a variable but neither the 0x5000000 value nor the 0x40021000 are stored in variables (RAM) since they are hard-coded. The code is built like if it were dealing with RAM, but the processor maps these accesses to the internal register.